# PHP won't connect to my MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$connect = mysql_connect("185.13.226.228", "xxxxx", "xxxxx") or die("Server is having problems at the moment. Please contact xxxx or xxx.");
```

That is my piece of code. It doesn't seem to connect to the IP. But I can connect to it manually. I hope you can help me out here.

Thank you.

Comment: Try with `localhost`, but if you are already stuck on the connection it's the perfect time to change to `PDO`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `or die(mysql_error())` to get the real error why.

Comment: You need to give us more details. Are you getting an error? How are you connecting manually?

Comment: Thanks, Rizier123. It worked. I'll try out PDO.

Comment: @user3849771 Your welcome! Added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with: `localhost`

Also i would highly recommend you to use and learn `PDO`.

Here is a good start:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php